# Rails 5 has_many and belongs_to : how to get the top level id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

For the following:

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
end


class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
end
```

If I have the call:

```
book.author.method1
```

Is it possible within method1 to get the book id (or any of the object's data)? (without having to pass it in as a parameter)

Comment: What is the nature of `method1`? Perhaps it would make sense to have `method1` be a method on `book` instead of `author`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access the child id in the parent model without passing it in, since it is a has_many relationship.  Seems you'll have to do something like:

```
book.author.method1(book.id)
```

Of course you could just pass the entire object, too.

Depending on what the method does, perhaps it is better suited in the book model?

Comment: I am doing something similar right now (passing in the object). Just feels a bit 'long-winded'.

Comment: If it feels wrong, it _probably_ is. Without more context I'd echo @jvillian's recommendation to put the method on `book`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, had a rethink.

```
author = book.author
author.method1(book)
```

This is a lot cleaner then what I had.

(Thanks for the feedback/comments)